# scrolling with mouse wheel in konsole

Tags: terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, scrolling, konsole

In konsole, mouse wheel scrolling events translate to up-arrow(`^[[A`) and down-arrow(`^[[B`) instead of the usual `^Y` and `^E`. Due to this, using mouse wheel in a konsole window results in scrolling through the shell history. How can I fix it and get the required behaviour?

Comment: What do you mean by "usual" `^Y` and `^E`? I've never heard of mouse wheel scrolling emitting these. Anyway, see https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=355106 for a relevant bugreport.

Comment: Run the `cat` command and scroll with the mouse wheel. You can also scroll up and down in a terminal with `C-Y` and `C-E`, in the terminals I've used at least

Comment: Ctrl+letter shortcuts are essential to applications running inside terminal emulators, terminal emulators don't grab them but forward them to the application. Shortcuts of terminal emulators typically require Ctrl+Shift. The scrollbar belongs to the terminal, apps running inside have no direct way of scrolling them back and forth. `^Y` and `^E` might be doing something in your shell on in the apps you typically run there. For me, in the shell (bash with pretty much the default settings) `^E` jumps to the end of the line, and `^Y` doesn't do anything.